# Calculate pairwise wilcox.test for several categories and plot significance in boxplot with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, plyr

I have a dataset that lookd pretty much like this one from diamonds:

```
diamonds2 = subset(diamonds, cut!='Good' & cut!='Very Good', -c(table, x, y, z, clarity, depth, price))
```

I want to make a boxplot like this one:

```
ggplot(diamonds2, aes(x=color, y=carat, col=cut))+geom_boxplot()
```

And the hard question comes here. My idea is to perform pairwise wilcox.test for each distribution of the variable y (carat) by group (cut) and for each of the columns (color).

```
library(plyr)

ddply(diamonds2,"color",
      function(x) {
          w <- wilcox.test(carat~cut,data=diamonds2)
          with(w,data.frame(statistic,p.value))
      })
```

The code fails because is asking for 2 levels (obviously). I can make a subset before applying the function (to remove one of the "cut") but It's not giving me what I want and can't understand why.

Additionally I would like to plot the results as asterisks of the color between the two distributions I'm comparing.
In the first boxplot (D), I would like to plot 3 asterisks, a purple (red and blue are significantly different), a yellow and a cian.

About the asterisk color plotting I've been playing a bit with the function geom_text from ggplot2 but I can't figure out how to plot below the X axis or plot text in different colors.

Comment: I don't know how one would correct a non-parametric test for multiple comparisons, but you should consider this.

Comment: pairwise.wilcox.test(diamonds2[,'carat'], diamonds2[,'cut'], p.adj = "bonf"). The problem here is that I cannot split by color, I should do it once for each column.

Comment: This does some more comparisons, but might be helpful: `pairwise.wilcox.test(diamonds2[,'carat'], interaction(diamonds2[,'cut'],diamonds2[,'color']), p.adj = "bonf"`

Comment: That's great! What about translating this information to the plot?

Comment: I don't understand your description of the desired plot. I would probably use the grouping letters scheme instead.

Comment: If 2 distributions are significantly different and their barplot colors are red and blue. The asterisk next to the name in the X axis would appear purple. And so on for all the pairwise comparisons.